# Simple redireccionamiento con Ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

estoy aprendiendo JQUERY y quiero hacer una simple redireccion en Ajax cuando se haga click en un  pero por alguna razón no me redirecciona.

```
$("#btn-proceed-chk").click(function(){

    var chkurl = "URL-DE-REDIRECCIONAMIENTO";

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: chkurl,
        success: function(data){
             window.location.href = 'url-de-redireccionamiento'
        }
    })})
```

Comment: Que error te arroja?

Comment: Failed to load http://website.com/un%20pedido: Redirect from 'http://website.com/un%20pedido' to 'http://www.website.com/un%20pedido' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.website.com' is therefore not allowed access.    No entiendo que puede llegar a ser.

Comment: Intenta poner window.location.replace('url-de-redireccionamiento')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primero debes de ter claro que esta sería una estructura básica para ejercer en tu documneto de JavaScript una llamada de cualquier tipo de método (POST, GET,..), e aquí un breve ejemplo del como podrías hacerlo con un evento de JavaScript:

**AJAX**

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#nombre_formulario', function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'nombre_mi_url.php',
    type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function()
    {
      $('.btn').val('Validando...');
    }
  })
  .done(function(respuesta)
  {
   console.log("Respuesta del servidor: ", respuesta);
  })
  .fail(function(answer)
  {
    console.log(answer.responseText);
  })
  .always(function()
  {
    console.log("completado");
  })
});
```

> **Nota:** Es recomendable que hagas uso de los scripts en direcciones por fuera de tu documento raiz de HTML, esto por mejores prácticas de programación.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mi_script.js"></script>
```

Segundo, si tu error persiste desde el retorno de tu servidor te arroja lo siguiente a lo que haces mencion en uno de tus comentarios:

> Failed to load website.com/un%20pedido: Redirect from
>   'website.com/un%20pedido'; to 'website.com/un%20pedido'; has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'website.com'; is therefore
>   not allowed access.

**Explicacion**

los datos que vienen vía AJAX tienen que pertenecer al mismo dominio. En el caso de que esto no sea así la aplicación no podrá cargar los datos por limitaciones de seguridad. Los problemas comienzan cuando nosotros tenemos aplicaciones que necesitan acceder a esos datos pero no se encuentran bajo el mismo dominio. Un ejemplo muy habitual es una aplicación Movil empaquetada con PhoneGAP o en Ionic con Angular. Por lo que en el momento en que subas tu app a un servidor esta responderá de forma correcta, es solo una limitación cuando se está trabajando de forma local (esto a manera de ejemplo en un ambiente parecido al mencionado)

**Solución**

Puedes descargar un complemento para el navegador sea Chrome(es más fácil) u otro de tu preferencia. Buscalo por ese nombre CORS y te ayudará, sólo tienes que ligar la dirección web a la que realizas tu petición con ajax. Y de esta manera permites la conexión entre ambas partes.

[image: CORS]

Otra posibilidad es que el documento o fichero al cual apuntas está codificado para evitar problemas de seguridad, y de esta manera no poder ser usada desde una aplicación externa (Un dominio X a un dominio Y).

Entonces, lo que harías sería usar este tipo de encabezados para que pueda recibir la peticion de forma correcta (Si en tu caso tienes acceso a tal fichero y claro, que sea el backend en PHP):

```
<?php 
  //Permisos CORS

  //* es un comodin para desplegar la información a cualquier servidor que realice la peticion.
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 

  //Debemos dar permisos de acuerdo a la llamada o metodo que necesites GET,POST,UPDATE.
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

  //Para formatos JSON se debe asignar el encabezado correspondiente.
  header("Content-Type: application/json");

 ?>
```