# API de League Of Legend con javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>



        var api_kei = "secreto";
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key="+api_kei;

        request.open('GET',url,true);

        request.onload = function () {

        }

        request.send();

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

> EL **Output de error** que me da es el siguiente:

```
>Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/RiotSchmick?api_key=secreto. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito).[Saber más]
```

Comment: Lo estas haciendo desde un ambiente en local ?, si tu respuesta es afirmativa te recomiendo seguir la respuesta marcada como la correcta en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195895/simple-redireccionamiento-con-ajax/195919#195919) donde abarco gran parte del posible error que estás teniendo

Comment: Deberías contextualizarnos en el problema que tienes, no basta con publicar sólo código colega. Sin embargo, el error que indicas es porque no puedes acceder a una API en específico por razones de seguridad asociados al desarrollo del mismo. Saludos =)

Comment: estas corriendo en un servidor, como nodejs, xampp o ngnix? las peticiones no suelen funcionar si tu web no está en un servidor.

Comment: A ver, yo lo que he hecho ha sido crear un **fichero.html** en mi escritorio y ejecutar ese **script** en una etiqueta **script**